# Modify a list of variables when passed as a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a ruby instance of a class (X) and a list of variables as a string ["var1", "var2", .. , "varn" ]. I have a function which will modify these values so that the net effect is something like this:

```
def modify(instance_obj, arrray_of_variables)
  # do something
end
```

Net effect should be:

```
X.var1 = modifyVar(X.var1)
X.var2 = modifyVar(X.var2)
..
X.varn = modifyVar(X.varn)
```

All the variables are assumed to be strings.

EDIT (more information): The actual problem I'm trying to solve is that for about 10 of my model classes, I have a few string variables I store in the db as JSON strings. So I have two functions parse_from_json (which should be called as after_find) and serialize_to_json (called as before_save). Since this will be done for quite a few model classes (around 10 model classes and a total of 30 variables or so), so I want to move it to a separate function instead of defining these functions for each model class.

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: You can add an instance method in the class and it will serve your purpose.

Comment: @muistooshort: Please see my original question EDIT for more information.

Comment: @sunny1304 please see EDIT in the original questio

Comment: Why not use the standard `serialize` support that's built into ActiveRecord? `serialize` is (IMO) a bit of a hack but what you're doing looks like working around a hack with more hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this.

```
def modify(instance_obj, arrray_of_variables)
  arrray_of_variables.each do |variable|
    instance_obj.send("#{variable}=", modifyVar(instance_obj.send(variable)))
  end
end
```